# Blank page on the very first install page on linux localhost - Opencart 1.5.4

Tags: opencart, ubuntu-13.04

I have followed the directions in the install.txt file.  My system is Ubuntu 13.04, raring. And I have mysql, which is all set up and ready.
This is what I did:
- downloaded opencart.
- copied files from upload folder to my main folder (localhost/j1/oc1/ )
- renamed the config.php file
- allowed permissions on all needed folders for writing
- try to load localhost/j1/oc1 and it redirects to localhost/j1/oc1/install/index.php
- blank page

Comment: Sorry if it's a dumb question, but it's the first time I'm using opencart, I have no clue about it. The documentation says you should automatically be greeted by the licence page - but all I get is a blank page, even with php error notifications on, so I'm at a loss. The only conclusion I can come to is that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the answer anywhere on stackoverflow, so I will post it here for others.

go into terminal, into your root folder and execute the following commands:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R

sudo usermod -a -G www-data username
```

This gives ownership of the opencart files to Apache.